# not able to pass parameter to function in python

Tags: python, pandas

How to convert below python code into function , so that when i call and pass parameter the function process and run

**Python code :**

```
import pandas as pd
data_xls = pd.read_excel('/demo/ab/excelfile.xlsx', 'Sheet1', dtype=str, index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I need like below :

```
def pyconv(function):
    var=path
    fname=filename
    import pandas as pd
    data_xls = pd.read_excel('var', 'fname', dtype=str, index_col=None)
    data_xls.to_csv('csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

**when i call function and pass parameter it should run :**

```
pycon(path,filename)
```

my function will take `var value : '/demo/ab/excelfile.xlsx' and fname=sheet1`

```
pycon('/demo/ab/excelfile.xlsx','sheet1')
```

Comment: Create an executable python script that takes the arguments as command line parameters. Then just put it on the $PATH and call it like you would any executable.

Comment: Are you asking how to turn this into a script you can call from a command line?  Because your question certainly does not make that clear.  You don't use parens in shell scripts.  Do you want `pycon /demo/ab/excelfile.xls sheet1` ?  Because that can certainly be done.

Comment: @codeholic24 : Why do you name your function `pyconv`, accepting one argument, but call it as `pycon`, passing two arguments? Python should produce an error message here.

Comment: @codeholic24: Why did you tag this _shell_? There is no POSIX shell code involved. And why did you tag it python2 **and** python3? Please make up your mind, which Python you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def pycon(path,sheet):
  import pandas as pd
  data_xls = pd.read_excel(path,sheet, dtype=str, index_col=None)
  data_xls.to_csv('csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

and now this shall work

```
pycon(r'/demo/ab/excelfile.xlsx','sheet1')
```

Comment: its working thanks can you add `import os` to your code

Comment: why?? we are not using os any where